# Android: Change the position andsize of ImageView programatically

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView inside LinearLayout. To change the position of this ImageView I am using MarginLayoutParams class. Below is the code.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/sample_frame" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/box" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Code for Padding**

```
MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) frame1.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(actualFrameX1, actualFrameY1, 0, 0);//all in pixels
frame1.setLayoutParams(mlp);
```

actualFrameX1 is left margin
actualFrameY1 is top margin
frame1 is IMageView

Upto here everything is working fine but the margins are changed when I set width and height of "mlp"
If the width and height are same, say 100px and 100px, then its fine but if width and height are different, say 85px and 100px, then the margins are changed.

```
MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) frame1.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(actualFrameX1, actualFrameY1, 0, 0);//all in pixels
mlp.width = 85;
mlp.height = 100;
frame1.setLayoutParams(mlp);
```

Below are the two screenshots - the top left corner of greenbox should match with that of white box

**Screenshot 1** - width and height are same (100 and 100)

**Screenshot 2** - width and height are different (85 and 100)

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

When I set mpl.width = 85 and mpl.height = 100 the image's padding changes as in the Screenshot 2. But if the width and height are same then the paddings are fine as in Screenshot. Why the paddings are getting changed? Please help me out.

Comment: what is your actual problem?please clarify it.

Comment: When I set mpl.width = 85 and mpl.height = 100 the image's padding changes as in the Screenshot 2. But if the width and height are same then the paddings are fine as in Screenshot. Why the paddings are getting changed?

Comment: @dipali Have you seen my code again?